# Why Kafka Producer call Failed to introspect Class

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I haven't enough expirience in Java and, especially in Kafka.
I tried to use a baeldung guide and this what i have now as a Config:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

 @Value(value = "${kafka.boostrapAddress}")
 private String bootstrapAddress;

 @Bean
 public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
 }

 @Bean
 public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
     Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
     configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            bootstrapAddress);
     configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class);
     configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class);
     return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
 }
}
```

And what I have in Util class for my autotests:

```
@Component
public class KafkaUtil {

 @Autowired
 private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

 public void sendMessage(String topicName, String msg) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, msg);
 }
```

And now my tests:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = CucumberSpringConfig.class)

public class ByKafka {
 private KafkaUtil kafkaUtil;

 private static final String topicName = "mytopic";

 @Autowired
 public ByKafka(KafkaUtil kafkaUtil) {
    this.kafkaUtil = kafkaUtil;
 }

 @Когда("тесткафка")
 public void sendTestMessage() {
    kafkaUtil.sendMessage(topicName, "hello");
 }
```

}

When I tried to run this test, i give next error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2437c6dc]
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:737) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:702) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:687) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at...

Comment: `@Когда("тесткафка")` - :smile:. Please, share more stack trace to determine what exactly field it fails on. Also would be great to have a link for "baeldung guide" for the whole picture of your environment.

Comment: `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` should be the proper config value, by the way, as per the spring-kafka documentation

Answer (score 4):

In my case this problem occurred when I upgrade Spring version and spring-kafka was incompatible. Try to **upgrade your kafka version**  to newer one.

```
    <!-- Kafka -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

mvn repo : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka

Kafka versions :
https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka